# mongoimport null field error

Tags: json, mongodb, null, mongoimport

i am trying to import a json file with fields containing NULL as a value

> [
>       {
>           'Id' : 0,
>           'Client' : 85,
>           'Campaign' : 0,
>           'Location' : NULL,
>           'Created' : NULL,
>           'CardCode' : NULL,
>           'Mobile' : NULL,
>           'Message' : NULL}]

when i try to use mongoimport to input these fields into a collection

> mongoimport --db dbname --collection coll filename.json --jsonArray

i get an error for the NULL value

> Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'U' in literal NaN or Number (expecting 'a' or 'u')

what would be the right way to import these documents?

Comment: Try *null* instead of *NULL*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you @joao.
that helped, changing the NULL to null solved the problem.

since it was a large file - i had to use sed to find and replace